# Multiple hasMany or belongsToMany relationships

Tags: laravel, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models Category and Object and relationship table `object_has_categories`.

Category:

```
public function objects() {

        return $this->belongsToMany(Object::class,Object::TABLE_CATEGORIES, Object::COL_CATID, Object::COL_OBJID );
}
```

Now, I want to split the `Object` table and relationship table into multiple tables. The tables have a predefined prefix (`<type>_objects` and `<type>_object_has_categories`).
I use the original class as a base (abstract class) and override TABLE property in the derived classes with the specific table name.

The number of `Object` tables (types) will be deployment-dependent.

**How can I write a method to return all objects for a given category?**

One way I just came up with is since I have a method to return all enabled object types, I can imagine a cycle to iterate over all `$this->belongsToMany(..)` relationships. But how to combine the results of multiple `belongsToMany` calls?

Comment: Hard to say with the information provided, but it sounds like you are looking for a [polymorphic relationshipship](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations). This will keep a single pivot table with a separate column to identify the specific type of object.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using a single pivot table because it will be quite big. And one of the reasons for splitting the tables was to benefit from a smaller table size for certain object types.

Comment: Unless we're talking more than like 5 million rows, a table with a couple of int columns and a single small text column will not be considered "big." It will be indexed so lookups will be very performant.

Comment: Well, one of the types is over 20 million rows (and growing) while the other types are in hundreds of thousands.
And the table is ±12 cols (1 string/varchar and others mostly ints)

Comment: I'm talking about the pivot table. That stores just the object and category IDs, and a label column saying which table the object is stored in. So you have multiple object tables, one category table, and one pivot table to tie them all together. And as I said, even approaching those sizes performance will be fine with indices. Or, be obtuse and jam together a bunch of collections. ‍♂️